# Dspace 6.3v - Cant make upload step non mandatory

Tags: dspace

I am using Dspace v 6.3 xmlui. I want to make the upload step of the submission form non mandatory. I followed the steps that the [wiki](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-ConfiguringtheFileUploadstep) stated and set the `webui.submit.upload.required` line to `false` in the `local.cfg` file of `[dspace-src]/dspace/config`, and then rebuild.
After that I checked, and the change in the line was taken by the correspondent files, meaning that:
The `dspace.cfg` of `[dspace-src]/dspace/config`
The `local.cfg` of `[dspace]/config`, and the
`dspace.cfg` file of the `[dspace]/config`, all have the requirement set to false.

But in the web application, the upload step is still mandatory, I cant skip it. When I try, it looks like this:
[image]
Does anybody knows why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure that the page was not cached, restart your Tomcat and try again or try submitting in incognito mode in your browser.

Comment: Also make sure that the line `webui.submit.upload.required` is uncommented, i.e. without the #.

Comment: Its working now, the problem was the # in the row. The summary view of the items is still showing predominantly the metadata associated with the file, but without the thumbnail, and with a legend that says that there are not files associated to the item. Can that be changed? I tried setting the line `xmlui.theme.mirage.item-list.emphasis` to `metadata` instead of `file`, but after rebuild and cleaning cache it didn't change. Is it the right configuration?

Comment: `xmlui.theme.mirage.item-list.emphasis` is applicable only for item-lists and discovery (search results) view. What you're seeing is the default or expected view in Mirage 1 theme. In Mirage2 theme, a default 'thumbnail' is displayed, but the text `There are no files associated with this item.` is still displayed in the full item view.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to modify that view in Mirage, right? It would still show the metadata "name, size, format and view" in both summary and full item view, but empty?